# Bulk forwarding to gmail bounces

Tags: gmail, postfix-mta, email-forwarding

I have built a system witch generates dynamic mail lists. 
It works by when a mail adress is changed in the system, PostFix mysql table gets updated with the new email adresses as Aliases. By doing this the mail sent to the group email adress gets forwarded to the final recipiant.

Flow:

```
(Anysender)
Incoming mail -----------------------|
                                     |
(Service end                         |
 user)        (MySql + PostFix)      V   (PostFix)
User update---->ServerAliases<-----VirtualMailBox
                 Forwarding
                      |
                      |
                      V
          (Any mail providers eg. Gmail)
             Mail sent to end user
```

This has worked fine for 3 years, but now suddenly all mail sent to gmail bounces. 
I am following all bulk sender guidelines. The error code from google says:

> said: 550-5.7.1 [80.241.87.18] The IP address sending this message does not
>       have a PTR 550-5.7.1 record setup.

I've checked the ptr reccords multiple times and they are accurate.

What am i missing?

Is there a other way to achieve this or some other caveats that I'm missing?